# Jquery selectors : property value begin with and end with

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-selectors, selector

I'm a beginner with Jquery and I have this little problem that I don't know how to fix. I've tried to debug with JSFiddle but I had no success so here my problem :

I have two div elements, in the first div I have several textboxes and in the second div I have my button. I would like that when I click on the button, a particular textbox in the first div become empty.

Okay, the whole picture is that I don't know the textbox name in advance (a list is fetch and ASP.NET MVC automatically names my input fields), so the only thing I know is that I want to empty the first textbox whose name property value finishes with "input1" (its beginning being auto-generated). I also know that the textbox I'm interested in is the one that immediately precedes my button. I hope I was clear.

Here is my Fiddle which is not working : http://jsfiddle.net/XvTNh/1/

Any help would be appreciate !

HTML:

```
<div class="myClass1">
<input name="fdsgginput1" type="text" value="Salé sucré"/>
<input name="gfsginput2" type="text" value="Macarons"/>
</div>

<div class="myClass2fdsff">
<input type="submit" name="envoyer" />
```

JS:

```
$("div[class^='myClass2']").on('click','input[name="envoyer"]',function(){
$(this).closest('input[name$="input1"]').val('');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically attempting to navigate around the DOM. `closest` does not go hunting for other elements that may be nearby in the HTML. Rather it goes up the DOM tree, looking at ancestor elements, and looks to see if any element matches the selector you pass.

Since the element you want is not an ancestor element, it will not be found.  You actually need to add a common ancestor element (in reality your HTML probably already contains one) and then combine `closest` and `find` to find the element:

```
$("div[class^='myClass2']").on('click', 'input[name="envoyer"]', function () {
    $(this).closest('.container').find('input[name$="input1"]').val('');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lonesomeday/XvTNh/4/)

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! I didn't know that closest couldn't hunt through divs, know I have a better picture of how Jquery works

Comment: Alternatively, something like `$(this).parent().prev().find('input[name$="input1"]').val('');` might also work, depending on the exact HTML structure.

Comment: @EiríkurFannarTorfason Indeed it would, but personally I find that relying on single-step traversal methods like `parent` and `prev` is much more likely to cause problems in the future, e.g. when HTML is modified.

Comment: @lonesomeday Fair enough. It's just that it isn't clear from the OP's markup that the divs are paired together in a container.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("body").find('input[name$="input1"]').first().val('');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, the problem with this answer is that my actual code is more complex than this. I have several elements whose name terminates with input1, and I don't even know if I am interested in the first of the page. (a list is fetched) Lonesomeday solution is the most appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myClass2fdsff input[type=submit]').click(function(){
         $('.myClass1 input:first').val(''); // Empty first textbox
         $('.myClass1 input[name*=input1]').val(''); //Empty input with input1 in name
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Joao. However it doesn't fit my actual need =/ Lonesomeday solution is what I was looking for!